# Typescript can't get cookie from Response object

Tags: angular, typescript, cookies, google-chrome-extension

in my google chrome extension I made post call that looks like this:

```
public someapiCall(username: string, password: string) {
    var url = 'http://test.someTestServer.com/api/user/someApiCall';

    let headers = new Headers({ 
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers, withCredentials: true });

    return this.http.post(url, 'UserName=' + username + '&Password=' + password, options)
        .map(res => {
            console.log(res);
            let cookies = res.headers.getAll('set-cookie');
            console.log(cookies);
        })
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

The problem is that when I call this, fiddler shows me these response headers:

[image]

but when I check Response object that is printed in console, it does not contain any header that references to cookie. Does anyone know where is the problem??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For security reasons most cookies are HTTP-only, look for `httponly` at the end of the cookie header:

```
Set-Cookie:.AspNetCore.Identity.Application=...; expires=...; secure; httponly
```

This means that the cookie is hidden from JS - the browser will hold it and include it with any request that you make to the domain/path, but client side JS cannot access it at all.

In a Chrome extension you can access these cookies, but not in a content script or injected code.

I'm using [`chrome-extension-async`](https://github.com/KeithHenry/chromeExtensionAsync) for `async`/`await` support, and the [`chrome.cookies` extension API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/cookies):

```
async function getCookies() {
    var cookies = await chrome.cookies.getAll();
    for(let cookie of cookies)
        // cookie.httpOnly will be true for the hidden cookies
        console.log(cookie); 
}
```